# Null Pointer exception while adding picklist value via apex using metadata

Tags: apex, picklist, metadata-api

I am just trying to see if its possible to add the value to picklist or not.
I am getting `Attempt to reference null pointer exception` on commented line.

Apex class

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = MetadataExamples.createService();
    MetadataService.CustomField customField =
    (MetadataService.CustomField) service.readMetadata('CustomField',
    new String[] { 'sii__Merchandise__c.sii__Test__c' }).getRecords()[0];
    System.debug(customField);

    MetadataService.Picklist picklist = customField.picklist;
    List <MetadataService.PicklistValue> picklistValues = picklist.picklistValues; // Error here
    MetadataService.PicklistValue picklistvaluenuevo = new MetadataService.PicklistValue ();
    picklistvaluenuevo.fullName = 'TEST';
    picklistvaluenuevo.default_x=false ;
    picklistValues.add(picklistvaluenuevo);
    picklist.picklistValues = picklistValues;
    customField.picklist = picklist;

    MetadataService.UpsertResult[] results = service.UpsertMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata [] {customField});
```

Comment: Are you getting nay value here `customField.picklist;`. Is this a picklist field?

Comment: That's the problem @tusharsharma. `customField.picklist` is coming as null.My picklist field is `sii__Test__c`

Comment: I am having a hard time to get this done for custom object. Anyone out there who can help me out?

Comment: You can get old picklist value using describe easily and then take help from sample code you can create new picklist field easily.

Comment: I am getting the same error when i am updating the custom as well as standard field on account. Is that the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using the  [Sample code](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls) Only change required was label name should be correct.

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = MetadataExamples.createService();
        MetadataService.CustomField customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
        customField.fullName = 'sii__Molecule__c.sii__Color__c';
        customField.label = 'Color';
        customField.type_x = 'Picklist';
        metadataservice.Picklist pt = new metadataservice.Picklist();
        pt.sorted= false;
        metadataservice.PicklistValue two = new metadataservice.PicklistValue();
        two.fullName= 'one';
        two.default_x=false ;
        metadataservice.PicklistValue three = new metadataservice.PicklistValue();
        three.fullName= 'two';
        three.default_x=false ;
        pt.picklistValues = new list<metadataservice.PicklistValue>{two,three};
        customField.picklist = pt ;
        List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results =
            service.updateMetadata(
                new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customField });
        MetadataExamples.handleSaveResults(results[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

As per discussion on Github by Andrew Fawcett

> I have confirmed with Salesforce. You cannot retrieve just
>   CustomFIeld's on their own, you have to retrieve the parent
>   CustomObject.

So you need to retrieve custom objects as well here.

[MetadataService.CustomField is always NULL and all Read Metadata Code returns NULL](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/issues/183)

[Sample Code](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls)

Comment: do i need to pass that custom object too as well while the field is being getting updated?

Comment: @Samir never tried this but I think yes.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the Tooling API to query the Metadata field from CustomObject, parse the JSON, then read the values from there.